# How to Display textfield when selecting a specific option from select box in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

On selecting random value from the dropdown menu, the text box should be displayed,
Ive made this but whenever 'random value' get selected in a single row 'text box' in every row gets displayed. how can i display the textbox according to the rows ?

```
  data = {"numerical":["one","two","random value"], "string":["mode","custom","random value"]};
```

```
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ product.ColumnName }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.DataType }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.NullCount }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.percentage }}</td>
            <td>
                <select name="" id="" class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event)">
                    <option value="" *ngFor="let option of getOptions(product.DataType)">{{option}}</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="text"  *ngIf="selectedType == 'random value'" >
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

```
onChange(event:any){
this.selectedType = event.target.value
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you give any UI desc. about what you want to achive.

Comment: Your onChange method need a scope. You are unable to know the selected type belongs to what. What you can do is to use reactive forms and each product is a form group inside the form. To display the textbox you can subscribe the form changes. The other simple but maybe not professional solution would to be store the date temporary on the product (or a view model extending the product).

Comment: @Storytellerr i have attached ui image, on that you can seein the first row i have selected 'random value', but the text area got displayed in both rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array of index accroding to the rows

change your code:

template:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product let-i="index">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ product.ColumnName }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.DataType }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.NullCount }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.percentage }}</td>
            <td>
                <select name="" id="" class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event, i)">
                    <option value="" *ngFor="let option of getOptions(product.DataType)">{{option}}</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" *ngIf="selectedTypes[i] == 'random value'">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

ts:

```
data = {"numerical":["one","two","random value"], "string":["mode","custom","random value"]};
selectedTypes: string[] = [];

onChange(event: any, index: number) {
    this.selectedTypes[index] = event.target.value;
}
```